# Quering nested document query with Mongoengine

Tags: mongoengine

I have been trying to Query some mongo instances variables with python and [MongoEngine](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/index.html) 
I need to get all the *Variable* from every *RegistroPozo* in all the Collection.

Example code:

```
from mongoengine import *
class Variable(EmbeddedDocument):
    mnem=StringField(required=True, max_length=200)
    description=StringField(max_length=500)
    unit=StringField( max_length=200,default='ppm')
    alias=StringField( max_length=200) #,default=mnem
    type=StringField( max_length=200,default='DEPENDANT')



class RegistroPozo(EmbeddedDocument):
    fecha = DateTimeField()
    filepath = StringField()
    start = FloatField()
    step = FloatField()
    stop = FloatField()
    variables = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Variable)
    registros = ListField(DictField())
    version_information_block = StringField(max_length=500)
    well_information_block = StringField(max_length=500)
    curve_information_block = StringField(max_length=500)
    parameter_information_block = StringField(max_length=500)
    other_block = StringField(max_length=500)


class Pozo(DynamicDocument):
  uwi_pozo = StringField(required=True, max_length=200, primary_key=True)
  nom_pozo = StringField(required=True, max_length=200)
  prof_total = FloatField(required=True)
  elev_terr = FloatField(required=True)
  long_pozo = FloatField(required=True)
  lat_pozo = FloatField(required=True)
  coord_x_po = FloatField(required=True)
  coord_y_po = FloatField(required=True)
  registros_pozo=EmbeddedDocumentListField(RegistroPozo)
```

When I try to query I make a lot of loops, but I belive there is a better way to do it.
Something like:

```
variables_in_all_the_doc = Pozo.objects(Q(AdvanceQuery))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pozo is a single document at mongo db level. Embeded document are just mongoengine constructs. So when you read Pozo objects, all embedded documents are also available in the same query (check with [mongostat](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/)). Now iterating on this data is not a big concern. For advanced EmbeddedDocumentList queries please read the docs [here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.base.datastructures.EmbeddedDocumentList).